# axios request cors issue even if headers are present on options call

Tags: laravel, vue.js, axios

App installed on subdomain 1: works fine. (app.subdomain.domain.com vuejs, subdomain.domain.com laravel backend)
App installed on subdomain 2: getting CORS.(app.subdomain2.domain.com vuejs, subdomain2.domain.com laravel backend)

Same files for app, same server and config (Vuejs and Laravel)

What i wonder... what's the deal with axios... OPTIONS call has the cors headers, but they are not passed through to the POST... WHY??

Here's a snapshot of the requests side by side and them failing on install#2.....

[image: Requests side by side]

Comment: Can you provide how you use `axios`?

Comment: I have figured it out... it was not axios...

Comment: Please provide your solution for everybody getting this error in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was that the laravel install was lacking a few permissions on the folder - and while it did not fail on OPTIONS, the subsequent GET/POST failed triggering the cors error, i was barking at the wrong tree apparently